# Does Datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') provide correct date considering DST?

Tags: sql, facebook, sqlite, datetime

To Clarify... I have an existing Facebook application Database table which stores DateTime in epoch time. I want to query the tables and display the DateTime in local time taking into account DST is appropriate.

Can anyone verify that the following SQL statement will properly account for DST (Daylight Savings Time) when showing the timestamp in local time (PST)? The timestamp is from a SQLite Facebook application (Apple).

```
Select Datetime(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') As ConvertedDateTime
  FROM XYZ
```

I've been searching all the sites, but haven't found a clear answer. A few pages I have found that discuss the subject include:

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Date-and-time-td15487.html

http://geeklog.lucid.net.au/article-20091211084306281.html?story=20091211084306281

[How do I convert from unix epoch time and account for daylight saving time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850605/how-do-i-convert-from-unix-epoch-time-and-account-for-daylight-saving-time-in-c)

Thank you for anyone that can clearly clarify this question.

Comment: Why is this tagged Facebook and not C#?

Comment: timestamp is from a Facebook application that I am trying to convert. From reading the 'Facebook' tag, this is the correct tag. I didn't include C# as I am not looking for a C# solution, but rather clarification on a SQL Statement. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `localtime` modifier asks the OS for the current time zone offset, so it will indeed take the DST into account (if it is set correctly in the OS).